# How to use grep to print lines until matching closing bracket?

Tags: grep, brackets

I have a document that has code like this:

```
Some words.

\NOTETAKING{ some text
 This is some {} text.
  This is more text \this{}.
}

Some more words.
```

How can I use grep to match the line starting with \NOTETAKING{, all text inside that bracket, until and including the line with the matching closing bracket?

- NOTETAKING can appear multiple times in the document, I need to find the nth occurance, e.g. sometimes search 1st occurance, sometimes search 3rd occurance.
- It always appears at the start of the line.
- Its closing bracket is always alone on its own line.

Comment: Is that the only place in the file where NOTETAKING and a closing curly bracket `}` being the last character on the line occur? If not, add more text from the document that shows where else they occur.

Comment: Yes, \NOTETAKING will always happen at the start of a line, and the end bracket will be by itself on a line, though there will be other end brackets like that too, so it must make sure it maches the matching braket.

Comment: Aside from `NOTETAKING`, does `\NOTETAKING` with the backslash at the start occur elsewhere in the file? Are there always the same number of lines between `\NOTETAKING` and the closing curly brace by itself?

Comment: \NOTETAKING{ with a later end bracket } can occur multiple times in the file. No, the number of lines is flexible, it could contain 1 or any number of lines between them.

Comment: `grep` isn't the correct utility for this because it can't print between strings on its own. `awk` or `sed` is better. I'll work on this and give an answer.

Comment: I can use Awk to do this on a single line, but this is split across lines. Can Awk search a start and end bracket, across lines, ignoring the wrong brakcets?

Comment: Yes. Both `awk` and `sed` can search across multiple lines and meet your criteria. Another tool that can do it is Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Perl is an option for you, here is a way to do the job.

I'm assuming the `}` that defines end of block is at the beginning of a line, If there can be some spaces before the `}`, use `/^\h*}/` instead of `/^}/`

**Code:**

```perl
perl -ane 'if(/\\NOTETAKING/ ... /^}/){$counter++ if /\\NOTETAKING/; print if $counter==2}' file.txt
```

**Input file:**

```
Some words.

\NOTETAKING{ some text 1rst occurrence
 This is some {} text.
  This is more text \this{}.
}

Some more words.
Some words.

\NOTETAKING{ some text 2nd occurrence
 This is some {} text.
  This is more text \this{}.
}

Some more words.
Some words.

\NOTETAKING{ some text 3rd occurrence
 This is some {} text.
  This is more text \this{}.
}

Some more words.
```

**Output:**

```
\NOTETAKING{ some text 2nd occurrence
 This is some {} text.
  This is more text \this{}.
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
perl -ane '                         # invoke Perl
if(/\\NOTETAKING/ ... /^}/){            # if we are between \NOTETAKING  & } at the beginning of line
    $counter++ if /\\NOTETAKING/;           # increment $counter if the line contains \NOTETAKING
    print if $counter==2                    # print current line, here for the 2nd occurrence, change the "2" with the occurrenec number you want to be printed
}                                       # endif
'                                   # end perl code
file.txt                            # input file
```